# ¿Cómo Rails genera el ID de un select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actualmente tengo dos vistas ambos tienen el mismo select_tag pero al recuperar el id veo que son diferentes.
[image: Aquí adjunto una imagen de como se ven ambas vistas.]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de las vistas donde está el `select_tag`?

Answer (score 0):

Rails genera los id de la forma `nombreclase_atributo`.Es decir si tienes una clase `Persona` y en sus atributos tienes `nombre` el formulario genera un `input` con `id="persona_nombre"` y en `name` recoge el valor eje `name="persona[nombre]"`.

Verifica en cada vista **html.erb** si los formularios tienen el mismo 
`input  <%= t.tipo_campo :atributo %>` Porque las imágenes muestran que no pasas los mismos parámetros. Saludos